# add 4 hours for UTC Time

Tags: php, utc

So i create a form outside of this calendar script I am using.

I am submitting a date from a Java Date Picker works great. The Only Problem is that the script that uses the date subtracts 4 hours based on it's needs.

Is there a way to add 4 hours to the submitted date so it shows up correctly in the admin when they go to approve the event that was submitted.

Example:

I submit the form 10:00 am 
the Admin the reads it as 6 am

The Code in the admin of the script is compensating for UTC.

```
<?php
   if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   ?>
   <?php
    } else {
   $input_arr = array();
   foreach ($_POST as $key => $input_arr) {

      $_POST[$key] = addslashes($input_arr);

   }
  $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
  $listing_id = $_POST['listing_id'];
   $status = $_POST['status'];
   $title = $_POST['title'];
   $description_short = $_POST['description_short'];
   $description = $_POST['description'];
   $venue = $_POST['venue'];
   $location = $_POST['location'];
   $admission = $_POST['admission'];
   $contact_name = $_POST['contact_name'];
   $website = $_POST['website'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $phone = $_POST['phone'];
   $date = $_POST['date'];
   $date_start = $_POST['date_start'];
   $date_end = $_POST['date_end'];



   mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pmd_events` (user_id, listing_id, status, title, description_short, description, venue, location, admission, contact_name, website, email, phone, date, date_start, date_end) VALUES ('$user_id', '$listing_id', '$status', '$title', '$description_short', '$description', '$venue', '$location', '$admission', '$contact_name', '$website', '$email', '$phone', '$date', '$date_start', '$date_end')");

   $id = mysql_insert_id();

   mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pmd_events_dates`     (event_id,date_start,date_end,rsvp_reminder_sent) VALUES ($id,'$date_start', '$date_end',0)");
   echo "verbage";
   }

   ?>
```

Comment: Please tag this question with the languages you are using, and other technologies. Just tagging `utc`, and with the current title, makes the question look language-agnostic

Comment: Isn't this script susceptible to sql injection? What if someone enters `','','','','','','')"); drop pmd_events; --` into `contact_name`?

Comment: An SQL error. Mysql as used here does not support multiple statements. Your principal stands though   just your example is poor

Answer (score 2):

Its very likely what's being submitted contains a time zone. The difference is what is submitted vs the submitters timezone.

Either don't send the time zone or trim the value to ignore the time zone. You could even do both

Comment: THis is the final time stamp in the database 2015-04-28 15:01:26